# msdropdown jquery plugin , how to change font color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have a problem with the MSDropDown plugin for jQuery.
Please take a look at this website: [www.baiads.com](http://www.baiads.com)

The problem is in the search block where you can see some red elements. How can I change the color from white to blue?

[image]

These elements show the select option in white, but will not work because the background is white too.

I tried to change my select style but nothing happens.
I tried to change the msdd style file too, but than nothing happens as well.

What else should I try?

Comment: Which red elements do you mean?

Comment: i just added image , it's the block under slider its select options , it work fine but the color of the selected option apper white and want to change from white to other color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'm answering the question. Do you mean the text displayed in the select box?

If you would like the text of the selected option to be a different colour change line 93 of dd.css to -

```
.dd2 .ddTitle span.ddTitleText {
    color: red; /* YOUR NEW COLOUR HERE */
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 33px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 1px;
}
```